# Hyper link, forms not working in Google Chrome and Firefox. They work fine in Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, hyperlink

I have changed the template of my website. It was working fine in the old template.
After this, the hyperlinks in the text fields and the form elements have stopped working.
Ex: http://agmrcet.com/cons/index.php/contact-us
http://agmrcet.com/cons/index.php/web-links

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
<div id="ry-footer" class="clearfix"></div>
```

It creates a div that covers the links, and text fields... so in Firefox and Chrome when you try to click a link, you really click the ry-footer and nothing happens.

Remove (or edit the style of that div), and it will work again.

Comment: Hi!That was amazing. Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me how you approached the problem? I want to learn something from this please. thanks once again